# Change position of imageview

Tags: android, fragment

I have problem, I have fragment activity with one textview and a button.
Whenever I click the button I can change the position of textView with .setY(500);
but how do I do it when my fragment loads? Because when I am trying to set it inside onCreateView it doesnt work and I need to change the position of my textView whenever fragment is loaded.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageView can be moved/edited as soon as the Layout has been loaded. You can add a listener to the ImageView in order to check when it's loaded and then move/edit the View. To do this you need to add a GlobalLayoutListener to the ViewTreeObserver of a View. Like this:

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //do something with the ImageView like move it.
         }
    });
```

Comment: @user2141889 No problem! If this answer was the one that helped you solve the problem please check it as the 'accepted answer', thank you!